# JQUERY load issues in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, load

I'm developing a site using JQUERY load function.  Works for all pages except the dynamic ones (Lookbook and catalogue).

View link here:

```
http://dev.denisduvauchelle.com/blp/b2b/index.php?language=fr#2-cravate-1
```

You'll notice in IE, the main window is empty, whereas in FF, Safari and Chrome no problem.  I copied the code for you here, since it is loaded you can't see it in the source:
http://dev.denisduvauchelle.com/blp/b2b/test.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

D

Comment: Can we see the link how you are loading the jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is a lot more fussy than the other browsers about HTML coming in via AJAX, it has to be valid.  Particularly with regard to tag matching, no mismatching.

Look at the validator output on your dynamic content:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://dev.denisduvauchelle.com/blp/b2b/test.php&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

> "end tag for element "div" which is not open"

Those have to go for it to work, otherwise IE will fail silently for the `load()` calls.

Comment: You gave me the right answer, but I can't get rid of all the errors.  check here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://dev.denisduvauchelle.com/blp/b2b/index.php%232-bdm-1&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.1

Comment: You can see that most of the errors are linked to the fact that in my JS script I have links with get method, "varx=hello&vary=hellotoo"... for example.

Comment: Any ideas?  I'm kind of stuck, it's the only errors I get now.

Comment: ***READ THIS FIRST****  I cleaned up also all the errors with the &.  The only errors I get now are the errors from the & in the the PHP function.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: @denislexic: All those ampersands `&` in the URLs are illegal in the HTML, you need to entity encode them.  Which for those means replacing the parameter separators with `&amp;`.